# Cyrus' Adventure (Part 4)

Tags: cipher, language

Cyrus opened the box carefully. Inside there was a strange totem made of metal. Cyrus decided to keep it. Suddenly, a cupboard opened by itself, and showed a secret passageway. Cyrus grabbed other things that might come in handy, and explored the passageway. It seemed safe, but after a while Cyrus faced three doors. There were some words on the three doors.
The first door wrote...

> Θις ις νοτ θε δοορ ψου σηουλδ γο

The second door wrote...

> ruguonixuanlezhedaomen,nijiangyongyuandebudaobaozang

The third door wrote...

> ^^-^^^^^^^-^^^^-^^^^-^^^-^^^-^^^^^^^^-^^^^-^^-^^^^

Which door should Cyrus choose?

> Hints: what do the symbols mean? What does '^' represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The third one

Why not the other two?

> first one: greek letters, translated to "This is not the door you should go"

and

> second one: chinese hanyu pinyin, which translates to "如果你選了這道門，你將永遠得不到寶藏" (english: "if you choose this door, you will never get the treasure")

Why that one then?

> haven't figured this out, but since it's not the other two it must be this one...

Comment: The third door wrote 'go through this door and the treasure will be yours'. The hyphens represent spaces.

Comment: Great! Yout got the correct answer :p